# Esconder videos em iframe safari

Tags: html, css, iframe, safari

Tenho um video de iframe do youtube dentro de uma div e quando faço hide na div, no safari, o video continua a aparecer. Como posso resolver isto?
Também me acontece que o video continua a reproduzir quando escondo a div, como posso parar o video?

Answer (score 1):

Estranho, não sei qual é a estrutura do seu html mas tente fazer:

```
<div class="my_vid">
   <iframe....></iframe>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.my_vid {
   width:600px;
   display: none;
   height:400px;
}

.my_vid iframe {
   height:100%;
   width:100%;
   display: block;
}
```

caso não resulte. acrescente à `.my_div`, isto é só um desenrrasque:

```
overflow:hidden;
height:0;
```

Answer (score 1):

Esta é a maneira que eu costumo fazer e nunca me deu qualquer problema.

```js
function toggleVideo(state) {
    var div = document.getElementById("vid");
    var iframe = div.getElementsByTagName("iframe")[0].contentWindow;
    div.style.display = state == 'hide' ? 'none' : '';
    func = state == 'hide' ? 'pauseVideo' : 'playVideo';
    iframe.postMessage('{"event":"command","func":"' + func + '","args":""}','*');
}
```

```html
<p><a href="javascript:;" onClick="toggleVideo();">Ver</a> </p>


<div id="vid" style="position:absolute;display:none;">
  
   <iframe width="500" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/fwVUO_Nk0oE" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
  
   <br /><br />
   <a href="javascript:;" onClick="toggleVideo('hide');">Esconde</a>
  </div>
```